# Why does #ifndef not work in this situation?

Tags: c++, redefinition

Note: The question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407905/how-to-prevent-multiple-definitions-of-functions-from-h-file) undirectly

> The problem is not include guards : they won't help across different
>   translation units

---

**Note: I know the solution is to use `extern` keyword.**

I'm new to C++. I have a problem understanding `#ifndef` in header files. When I do something like this, I get an error saying that the variables `game_over` and `turn` are already defined.

```
/*chess.h*/
#ifndef CHESS
#define CHESS
#include <iostream>
#include "chessboard.h"
using namespace std;

bool game_over;
char turn;
chessboard board;

int main();
#endif

/*bishop.cpp*/
#include "bishop.h"
#include "chess.h"
bishop::bishop(string pos, char color)
{
    int x = pos[0] - 97;
    int y = pos[1] - 1;
    name = "bishop";
    this->color = color;
    board.add_new(*this);
}

/*chess.cpp*/
#include "chess.h"

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

Why are the variables defined twice in here? I thought that first time when `chess.h` is included, `CHESS` is defined. So in bishop.cpp, `#include "chess.h"` will not do anything since the header will skip to `#endif` from `#ifndef CHESS`. But it does not work like that obviously. Why am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have any *other* source files that also `#include "chess.h"` that you're linking with this one?

Comment: Are you including this file in multiple cpp files?  If so, each one will have the variable declarations in it.

Comment: Yes, I do. So I don't get why we use #ifndef if it does not prevent this problem from happening?

Comment: `int main();
#endif` Really? O_o ,,,

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use extern in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent multiple definitions of functions from .h file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407905/how-to-prevent-multiple-definitions-of-functions-from-h-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#ifndef` only blocks the code if the symbol is defined within the same translation unit, at a point before the `#ifndef`. A translation unit is a source file (.cpp) and all the files that are included into it. Since you're compiling two source files, they'll both have a complete include of the .h file.

You already appear to know how to handle the problem of defining global variables in a header file: declare them `extern` in the header, and put a definition into one of the sources. I would be remiss though if I didn't warn you to avoid globals in the first place, as your programs grow they'll make your life difficult.